# Drawing shapes on a HTML canvas on bases of grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am developing an application to design event map in HTML 5 canvas.

Here is an example of map i want to create
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGvTg.jpg

I have made the canvas. I want to know how to draw stall on specific grid boxes of the canvas. 
Scale : 1 box of grid in canvas = 1sq ft.
Ex. I want to draw a 4X3 stall between (3,3) & (6,6) grid point of canvas Then how to draw it on the canvas...

Canvas code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style=" background: lightblue;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="420px" height="420px" style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;">
Browser does not support canvas 
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var bw = 400;
var bh = 400;
var p = 10;
var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
function drawBoard(){
for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 40){
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
}
for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 40) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
 }
 context.strokeStyle = "black";
 context.stroke();
}
drawBoard();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style=" background: lightblue;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="420px" height="420px" style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;">
Browser does not support canvas 
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var bw = 400;
var bh = 400;
var p = 10;
var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

var grid = 40;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBoard(){

 context.beginPath();
 for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += grid){
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
 }
 for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += grid) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
 }
 context.lineWidth = 1;
 context.strokeStyle = "black";
 context.stroke();

}
drawBoard();

function drawRect() {

 context.beginPath();
 context.rect(0.5+p+3*grid, 0.5+p+3*grid, 4*grid, 3*grid);
 //context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
 //context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 3;
 //context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
 context.stroke();

}
drawRect();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel.. Thisis exactly i wanted... Can you please describe the logic of how you did it if possible.. I have to manually enter the stall co-ordinates via a form to draw stalls in canvas.. So the the logic will help me obtaining value through text boxes..  Thanks a lot..

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. The logic is the same as you had used to draw the grid. The grid is 40px wide and high, so 3*grid is the start point of the 3th grid square in width and heigth.

Comment: Ohkkk.. Understood... I made the map... Thanks a lot friend.. :) :) :)